# does Asymmetric Encryption(private-key) and Decryption (public-key) exist? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encryption-asymmetric

i know that the default is that you have a public key to encrypt messages and a private key to decrypt the encrypted messages.

I need this turned around so that the public key can read the message and the private key can encrypt it.

My Goal is to generate a License Key for my software(NodeJS) which is given in with an ENV and i want to read than the License Key in Nodejs with the built in public Key to verify that the key got created by me.

Maybe there is a better solution for this?

Searched for basicly a switched Asymmetric Encryption variant.

Comment: That's called "signing" ... No need to encrypt your data. A licensefile probably does not include anything secret. Just add the signature ...

Comment: A more or less ready to use technique for this could be using a JWT.